# "disconnect" event on client and server side (Socket I/O)

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

- Client Side :
  `socket.on('disconnect')` is called when client does not receive pong response from server after `pingTimeout` has passed(Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31119691/socket-io-specifying-heartbeat/31787022#31787022))
- Server Side :
  Similarly, server also has `disconnect` event for the each socket instance. When is this event triggered on server? Is there a specific timeout for this also like client side `disconnect` event.

  ```
  io.sockets.on('connection', function(client){
    client.on('disconnect', function(room){
       ///
    });
  }
  ```